# How to format binary representation of RGB colour?

Tags: number-systems

If I convert, say, #FF$1919$ to binary, I can do it in groups of three bytes like:

FF: $1111$ $1111$

$19$: $0001$ $1001$

$19$: $0001$ $1001$

So can I write that #FF$1919 =$ $1111$ $1111$ $0001$ $1001$ $0001$ $1001$?

Or do I have to write them as separate bytes like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is absolutely fine. You could have also done it as:
$$F: 1111$$
$$F: 1111$$
$$1: 0001$$
$$9: 1001$$
$$1: 0001$$
$$9: 1001$$
and combined in the same way

So $FF1919: 1111\space 1111\space 0001\space 1001\space 0001\space 1001$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the positional systen works as expected:
$$
(FF1919)_{16} 
= 15 \cdot 16^5 + 15 \cdot 16^4 + 1 \cdot 16^3 + 9 \cdot 16^2 + 1 \cdot 16^1 + 9 \cdot 16^0 \\
$$
Then we have 
$$
16^k = (2^4)^k = 2^{4k}
$$
so
\begin{align}
(FF1919)_{16} 
&=
(1111)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 5} +
(1111)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 4} +
(0001)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 3} +
(1001)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 2} + \\
& \quad \,
(0001)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 1} +
(1001)_2 \cdot 2^{4\cdot 0} \\
&=
1\cdot 2^{23} +
1\cdot 2^{22} +
1\cdot 2^{21} +
1\cdot 2^{20} +
1\cdot 2^{19} +
\dotsb \\
& \quad \,
1\cdot 2^{3} +
0\cdot 2^{2} +
0\cdot 2^{1} +
1\cdot 2^{0} \\
&=
(1111 \, 1111 \, 0001 \, 1001 \, 0001 \, 1001)_2
\end{align}